# Flutter Navigation: Fetching the previous Route

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been doing some flutter development lately out of interests and I came upon the flutter navigator. I am using the default style way, so no routing lib is used(just Navigator.push/pop), however I would like to be able to fetch the previous route of the current rout(in other words fetching the route that initialised and called the current one.

At the moment I have a final field in each Route where I can recognise the caller, however this is a very bad way of doing it in addition of being unpractical especially when I have composed classes.

Any idea of how this can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: so you want to get he parent's [Route](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html) object?

Comment: If you mean by parent, the class that has called or navigated to the new route, then yes I would like to get it. The reason why I am asking this, I have a generic screen that can be used in different situations during the life cycle of the app. Based on the caller of this screen, it has to call other screens.

Comment: what about adding your own listener to [observers](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/observers.html) property?

Comment: or maybe https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html (i have no idea how to use it though, as i "found" it 30 seconds ago...)?

Comment: I am actually reading about it, I never used it either and didn't have the need for it. The interesting part is, there is an open ticket in the Flutter Repo, regarding something similar.

Comment: so first try to extend `NavigatorObserver`, add it to `Navigator.observers` property and you will be able to observe each push and pop made by `Navigator`

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand the use case you've mentioned, it seems that you'd like to fetch the previous Route when the app navigates to a generic screen. In this generic screen, it checks the Route where it came from to call other Screens.

[Navigator 2.0](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) should be able to cater this use case. I suggest using the `pages` argument in the Navigator constructor. This should help keeping a list of `Page` objects in tab and be able to update the Screen as needed. This [blog post](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade#55f7) has a complete sample that you can try out.